# Aurora Postgres Minor Version Upgrade

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

AWS requests upgrading Aurora Postgres from 12.4 to 12.7, I am trying to understand if there will be downtime during this upgrade and how I can avoid it but unfortunately I cannot find a clear answer. What is the suggested way to avoid downtime or at least minimise the duration?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon [documents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html) the overall process and tells you how to do it manually if you want.  When I upgrade a local PostgreSQL instance the minor upgrade process is extremely quick but there isn't a guarantee that the RDS version will be as fast, especially depending on your configuration (multi AZ, read replicas, etc.).  I doubt the downtime will be zero but, again, your setup is the big factor.

Answer (score 0):

AWS recently introduced [Zero-downtime-patching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html#USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.Minor.zdp), for Aurora PostgreSQL (regional) clusters.

But not applicable for Aurora Serverless and Aurora global databases, so there will be downtime in these cases, depending on cluster setup.